# Counting the number of elements in a list: how affectation works

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I was working on a Prolog problem consisting in counting the number of elements of a list:

```
count([], 0).
count([H|T], N) :-
    count(T, X),
    N is X+1,
    N > 0.
```

I can understand why it's written like that but I don't understand why we can't replace N is X+1 by **X is N-1** ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Minor nit: affectation means rather assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is very legitimate, +1.

The reason for this seemingly arbitrary choice is that `(is)/2` is a comparatively low-level predicate and only works in very specific cases that can only be understood procedurally, not declaratively. Therefore, `(is)/2` is extremely hard to understand for beginners and should better be avoided because it destroys many relational properties we want to enjoy when using Prolog.

The declarative solution is to use **constraints**, where you can do exactly what you say. For relations over integers, simply replace `(is)/2` by `(#=)/2` to enjoy the relational properties you intuitively expect.

For example, using GNU Prolog:

```
count([], 0).
count([_|Ls], N) :-
        count(Ls, X),
        X #= N - 1,
        N #> 0.
```

In other systems like SICStus Prolog and SWI, you currently still need to use `library(clpfd)` for this. In addition, I highly recommend a more declarative name for this relation, making clear which argument denotes what:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

list_length([], 0).
list_length([_|Ls], N) :-
        list_length(Ls, X),
        X #= N - 1,
        N #> 0.
```

Sample queries:

```
?- list_length([_,_,_], N).
N = 3.

?- list_length(Ls, 2).
Ls = [_G602, _G605] .
```

I leave improving the termination properties of this predicate as an easy exercise.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer mat! At the beginning of your answer, you said that (is)/2 works in very specific cases. Do you know where I could find more informations about this ? In the SWI-Prolog website, it says that it should be used with unbound left operand, but it's not very clear to me (In my lessons, it says "The right-hand term should be fully instantiated at the time of the call.").

Comment: It's no wonder that this is not very clear for you: Especially as a beginner, you have almost no chance to understand how `(is)/2` must be used. For later reference, I only let you know that its right-hand side must be fully instantiated, and its left-hand side should be a variable *at the time the goal is called* (ugh!). But why even bother with this logic *hacking* instead of logic *programming*? Use `(#=)/2` and `(#>)/2` throughout, and enjoy the relational nature of these predicates, which are usable in **all** directions. I have added more explanations about this to my answer.